# Sack with different weights, what has to be the diff for it to work

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Question: I have a sack which can carry some weight, and number of items with weight and i want to put as much weight as possible in the sack to carry, after some thought I have got into a conclusion, I take the highest weight every time and put into the sack, intuitivaly that it will work if the weights that are given are incremented atleast by multiplication of 2. For e.g. 2 4 8 16 32 64.. 
Can anyone help me prove if I am right or wrong about that?  I have also an intuition about that, would love to hear urs.

Note: thought about saying that the sum of the previous numbers wont be bigger of the current nunber.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question? You have a sack which can move items, you have items with weight. Is the question "can I move all the items so that each time the total weight moved to one side is more than the remaining weights"? It's really not clear from the question.

Comment: @Assafs edited.. :)

Comment: 1. Can you improve the question title please? What does "diff for it to work" mean? The concept of "diff" is not explained in your question body. 2. Are we to suppose that item weights are not a given to the problem? Why are you even considering a 2 - 4 - 8 ... series at all? And what about the total number of items, is it a given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, described [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) will work for powers of two.

Note that partial sum of geometric sequence `1,2,4,8,16..2^(k-1)` is `2^k-1`, that is why you always should choose the largest possible item - it is always bigger than any sum of smaller items.

In mathematical sense set of 2's powers forms [matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid)

But it would fail in general case (example - 3,3,4 and sum 6). You can learn for dynamic programming to solve this problem with integer weights. It is similar to [knapsack problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/) with unit item costs.

Comment: Prove what suggestion? You even did not state the problem clearly. To prove that greedy algo gives the smallest subset to form needed sum, one can use geometric progression sum property.